# Increase or decrease multiple input number values in Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a price list for Hotels, where values are placed in table. Each row in the table represents a room, and each column in the table represents a season for the rooms. 
In every field there is a html input field with number value (price) for room in particular seasons. 
I need to create functionality where user will be able to **Increase or decrease** price for one room in all seasons (multiple input fields) for some **percentage or fixed amount**. 
Can someone point me or give me idea on how to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Is the user want to select one room THEN modify the price - Or be able to get all the rooms list & modify all season room's prices in 1 step ? BTW you DB has a serious pbm of normalisation . Let's see in 15 seasons u'll have 15 additionnals columns in this table - Should think about it too.

Comment: There is at most 5 seasons. 
Yes, user should be able to select one rooms prices throughout seasons. 

I can get values from that price fields, but I am not sure how to manipulate them in a way they can be increased or decreased for fixed amount or percentage..

Comment: Basically u.ll have to loop through ur result query (the prices of hotel room) echoing name room / price + input type="number" (for the new price). Considering parsing this post variable for % or raw new price. Search in stack about 'array input html' to store all these vars into an array.